# Logging inside a bash script file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging

I have a pretty large script ( functions contains around 4000 lines of code) . Here is a part of it :

```
#!/bin/bash 


. ./functions > /dev/null 2>&1

some_function(){

while true
do

CHOICE=$(whiptail --menu "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" --title "Tools" --nocancel $window 20 \
"1" "Option1" \
"2" "Option2" \
"3" "Option3" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)


case $CHOICE in

    1)echo $1 $2 $3;;
    2)echo $2 $1 $3;;                                       
    3)echo $3 $2 $1;;

esac
done
}



while true; do 
arr=()
for ((n=1; n<=$node_num; n++))
        do
        node+=($n NODE$n)
done


OPTION=$(whiptail --menu "\n\n\n\nPlease choose:\n\n\n" --title "tools" $window 20 "${node[@]}" \

case $OPTION in

        1) some_function 1 2 3 ;;  
        2) some_function 2 1 3 ;;
        3) some_function 3 1 2 ;;
esac
done
```

I want to log the commands executed in the script.

What I have tried so far is :

1. `#!/bin/bash -x`   --> this will log all the output , but will also "spam" the logs with unneeded information like variable values etc. However this seems to be the best way so far...
2. I have tried  `#!/bin/bash -i` , enabling history with set -o history . The disadvantage of this is it will log everything . When I call the function file for example it will log every single line as if it was executed .
3. I have tried creating a log function :

   ```
   logthis(){
       ## print the command to the logfile
       echo "$(date) $@" >> $historyfile
       ## run the command and redirect it's error output
       ## to the logfile
       eval "$@" 2>> $historyfile
   }
   ```

   This seems to work most of the time. But when I do, for example:

   ```
   case $OPTION in
       1) logthis "some_function 1 2 3" ;;  
       2) some_function 2 1 3 ;;
       3) some_function 3 1 2 ;;
   esac
   ```

it will not work as I will lose the arguments 1 2 3

Do you have any other ideas of doing an elegant logging system inside a bash script?

Comment: Tracing can be enabled and disabled as needed within your script using `set -x` and `set +x`; it's the finer-grained version of your option 1.

Comment: Option 2 doesn't require the `-i` option; history is enabled by default in an interactive shell, but does not *require* an interactive shell.

Comment: yes, I can enable and disable debug mode , but was searching for more elegant way instead going through all the code and setting set -x / set +x

Comment: Here is a comprehensive implementation of logging for bash: https://github.com/codeforester/base/blob/master/lib/stdlib.sh

Answer (score 7):

Get rid of the `eval` in your log function. Just write `"$@"` to execute the passed command.

```
logthis() {
    echo "$(date): $@" >> "$historyfile"
    "$@" 2>> "$historyfile"
}
```

Then you can log a command by simply prepending `logthis`. No need for extra quotes.

```
logthis some_function 1 2 3
```

This will very nicely preserve all the arguments--even if they have whitespace or other special characters.

I'd recommend a minor improvement to the `echo` command as well. If you use `printf %q` it'll log arguments with whitespace better.

```
echo "$(date):$(printf ' %q' "$@")" >> "$historyfile"
```

Comment: For the last bit , why not just use printf for the whole thing ?

Comment: `printf` will repeat the format string for each extra argument. Can't do that and print the date in one `printf`.

Comment: unfortunately when I try to pass variables for example : logthis command $1 $2 something breaks and the whiptail window doesnt display ... :/

Comment: You should write a whiptail-specific question if you continue to have problems. I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: here is a link to something I found regarding whiptail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970180/whiptail-how-to-redirect-output-to-environment-variable , so it seems that whiptail is switching fd which makes it impossible to use the logthis function in all cases .

Answer (score 2):

Try `set -v`

That doesn't parse the commands like `set -x`, just outputs what gets executed.

```
set -v
: all the things 'in' $0, 'yay!'
```

outputs exactly `: all the things 'in' $0, 'yay!'`
Doesn't even parse $0.

Arguments recorded, minimal spam. ;)

Consider wrapping curlies around the main block of code to manage output logging.

```
{ # after setup to parse args, set vars & traps, declare funcs, etc
  your bulk code here
} 2>&1 | tee /some/file.log
```

You can save the `set -x` spam for `--verbose` mode. ;)

Comment: Thanks , but this still will log also all the whiptail menus for example. I cant output them to /dev/null like the variable declarations for example.

Comment: Can you abstract the menus to a function that turns -v off at the start and on at the end? You're asking for granular logging, so I'm afraid you're going to have to write granular code.